# Overlapping Collider2D Triggers

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok lets get into it.

I've got 2 colliders whose purpose it is to determine the hit type of the ball. If it is **GoodHit** or **NiceHit** (Nice is like Perfect).

The **GoodHit** collider2d has a much larger area than **NiceHit**.
The **NiceHit** on the other hand overlaps to a portion of **GoodHit** in its center.

Using this code I can determine whether the ball enters the area of **GoodHit** and **NiceHit**

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.name == "HitNice") {
            hitType = 2;
        } else if(other.name == "HitGood") {
            hitType = 1;
        }
    }

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.name == "HitNice") {
            hitType = 2;
        } else if(other.name == "HitGood") {
            hitType = 1;
        }
    }

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
            hitType = 0;
    }
```

The problem is it doesn't triggers the NiceHit and the hitType is still valued 1 regardless if the ball is in NiceHit area.

I first created the Goodhit object, that in a sense gives it a priority than NiceHit. I could swap them by names and values that way I can achieve the thing that I wanted but that doesn't really solved it.

Any workaround or tweaks I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Well, having two trigger colliders seems like a bad idea in my opinion because if someone scores a nice hit, then the good hit will be triggered as well. Depending on wich one makes the race you may get an invalid result. I would try to use a single trigger collider and experiment with the hitpoint (distance from hit point to center). That may already solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two overlapping triggers, one of which is in the middle of a larger trigger.

Here's something to remember: *if an object is inside the inner trigger, it is also inside the larger trigger!*

So in your code, you use `OnTriggerStay` to determine if the object is in one of those triggers. Let's take a look at that:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.name == "HitNice") {
        hitType = 2;
    } else if(other.name == "HitGood") {
        hitType = 1;
    }
}
```

This function is executed once per trigger that the object is inside of. So this function is executed twice if it is inside of the `HitNice` trigger. So let's say Unity calls this function for each trigger. What is probably happening is that it's calling the handlers in a bad order (pseudocode):

```
OnTriggerEnter(HitNice) //hitType is 2
OnTriggerEnter(HitGood) //hitType is now 1!
```

Unity is calling the collider handlers from inside out, causing the result from a `HitGood` trigger to always override the `HitNice` value. I don't know for sure if that's how it works, but looking at your code it's totally a possibility of why it's not working correctly.

Now, I can't say this for sure, but I think just using your `OnTriggerEnter` handler will suffice. It will only trigger the `hitType` detection when it enters a collider rather than when it stays. Since the object *must* enter the outer trigger before entering the inner trigger, this means that it should always evaluate in the correct order. In that case, your code is probably working as is, but I would say that your logic should be like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if(other.name == "HitNice") {
        hitType = 2;
    } else if(other.name == "HitGood" && hitType != 2) {
        hitType = 1;
    }
}
```

The only caveat of this approach is that you would need to reset the value of `hitType` manually. Not sure exactly how your game works, but this should give you an idea of how to approach this. Your `HitNice` should *always* override a `HitGood`. So when `OnTriggerEnter` is called for `HitGood`, check that you haven't yet hit `HitNice` yet. Or even better, record both hit types in separate variables, and then resolve which type of hit it was later on when doing scoring or whatever.

Comment: your `other.name == "HitGood" && hitType != 2` gave me an idea. thanks bud. But I can't use `OnTriggerEnter2D` only because when the ball is too fast, it skips a frame that supposedly will touch the edge of the collider causing it not to trigger the `Enter2D`

Comment: I've had that happen before, it's frustrating! Glad you figured it out.